# Transform list into dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have following dict:

["sector", "food", "delivery"]

How can I create with this list following dict:

```
    "sector": {
        "food": {
            "delivery": {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try writing code to solve the problem? What difficulty did you encounter while doing so? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list and add a dictionary for each key:

```
>>> n = nested = {}
>>> for k in ["sector", "food", "delivery"]:
...     n = n.setdefault(k, {})
...
>>> nested
{'sector': {'food': {'delivery': {}}}}
```